# defining variables and executing a variable python

Tags: python, variables

Having some problem with this code. When I input 2 to try and execute `whaleq()`, it executes `mathschallenge()` instead, which I want to be executed only when the user inputs 1.

Can anyone take a look and help me fix this? The code below is the exact same as the code that I have in my python idle.

```
print('The first thing you should think about doing is asking the locals if they have seen     anything!')

locallist = ['Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)',
             'Bella, the flourist (2)',
             'Caitlyn, the painter (3)',
             'Daniel, the scientist (4)',
             'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
print(locallist)

localpick = int(input('Type the number of the local you want to talk to '))

def localx():
    if localpick == 1:
        mathschallenge()
    if localpick == 2:
        whaleq()

def mathschallenge():
    print('maths challenge yolo')
    quest = input('What is 10+10?')
    if quest == '20':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')

def whaleq():
    mammal = input('What is the largest mammal?')
    if mammal == 'whale':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')

input('Press the enter key to exit')
```

Comment: After taking 'localpick' value from user were are you calling the 'localx' function.

Comment: I hope this is not your exact code. It's not indented properly.

Comment: changed localx to localpick and it didnt do anything different. And @RvdK I had to paste the code then indent it on here with the 4 spaces things. so it may be off

Comment: Well localpick is your variable holding user input. And localx is the function is needed to be called once you have got your user option which is missing. So you need to call your function localx after you take input from user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine for me other than reorganising a little, I moved:

```
print('The first thing you should think about doing is asking the locals if they have seen     anything!')

locallist = ['Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)', 'Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the 
painter         (3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
print(locallist)

localpick = int(input('Type the number of the local you want to talk to '))
```

From the top of the code to the bottom,and adding `localx()` just above:

```
input('Press the enter key to exit')
```

So the Whole code looks like this:

```
def localx():
    if localpick == 1:
        mathschallenge()
    if localpick == 2:
        whaleq()

def mathschallenge():
    print('maths challenge yolo')
    quest = input('What is 10+10?')
    if quest == '20':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')

def whaleq():
    mammal = input('What is the largest mammal?')
    if mammal == 'whale':
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')


print('The first thing you should think about doing is asking the locals if they have seen     anything!')

locallist = ['Ann-Marie, the butcher (1)', 'Bella, the flourist (2)', 'Caitlyn, the painter     (3)', 'Daniel, the scientist (4)', 'Lauren, the Zookeeper (5)']
print(locallist)

localpick = int(input('Type the number of the local you want to talk to '))
localx()
input('Press the enter key to exit')
```

I hope this Helped,
~Bobbeh

NOTE: This was tested in python 3.4.2